# How to apply a filter to a section of a Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, filter, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe **df** that looks like this:

```
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|id   |gender|salary|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
|James    |          |Smith   |36636|M     |3000  |
|Michael  |Rose      |        |40288|M     |4000  |
|Robert   |          |Williams|42114|M     |4000  |
|Maria    |Anne      |Jones   |39192|F     |4000  |
|Jen      |Mary      |Brown   |30001|F     |2000  |
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
```

I need to apply a filter of **id > 4000** only to **gender = M**, and preserve all the **gender = F**. Therefore, the final dataframe should look like this:

```
 +---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|id   |gender|salary|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
|Michael  |Rose      |        |40288|M     |4000  |
|Robert   |          |Williams|42114|M     |4000  |
|Maria    |Anne      |Jones   |39192|F     |4000  |
|Jen      |Mary      |Brown   |30001|F     |2000  |
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
```

The only way I can think of doing this is:

```
df_temp1 = df.filter(df.gender == 'F')
df_temp2 = df.where(df.gender == 'M').filter(df.id > 4000)
df = df_temp1.union(df_temp2)
```

Is this the most efficient way to do this? I'm new to Spark so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would `df.filter("(gender == 'M' and id > 40000) or gender == 'F'")` help?

Comment: Although werner's answer is perfect and precise. I would rather suggest to use the same thing you mentioned in your Question , at least it's more readable. Because Spark will probably end up doing the same work / end up using the code which werner wrote because of the the Catalyst optimizations . There won't be any performance improvement.

Comment: pls see the answer below with filter() and let us know if that helps you - appreciate if you can help accept and upvote

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. `where` is an alias for `filter`.

```
>>> df.show()
+-------+------+-----+
|   name|gender|   id|
+-------+------+-----+
|  James|     M|36636|
|Michael|     M|40288|
| Robert|     F|42114|
|  Maria|     F|39192|
|    Jen|     F|30001|
+-------+------+-----+

>>> df.where(''' (gender == 'M' and id > 40000) OR gender == 'F' ''').show()
+-------+------+-----+
|   name|gender|   id|
+-------+------+-----+
|Michael|     M|40288|
| Robert|     F|42114|
|  Maria|     F|39192|
|    Jen|     F|30001|
+-------+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

use both the condition using **`OR`**

**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(36636,"M"),(40288,"M"),(42114,"M"),(39192,"F"),(30001,"F")],["id","gender"])
df = df.filter(((F.col("id") > 40000) & (F.col("gender") == F.lit("M"))) | (F.col("gender") == F.lit("F")))
df.show()
```

**
**Output**

```
+-----+------+
|   id|gender|
+-----+------+
|40288|     M|
|42114|     M|
|39192|     F|
|30001|     F|
+-----+------+
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me what the .lit() does?

Comment: PySpark SQL functions lit() and typedLit() are used to add a new column to DataFrame by assigning a literal or constant value. Both these functions return Column type as return… So, assume here you need to compare with some string - so in that case wrap that with lit()

Comment: Can you please accept and upvote my answer - this helps :)